# Cannot install Wordpress locally on OS X without MAMP

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, macos-high-sierra

I'm following the excellent tutorials first [here](https://mallinson.ca/osx-web-development/) then [here](https://www.davidgagne.net/2017/01/23/the-ultimate-guide-to-local-wordpress-development-on-a-mac/). I think I succeeded with most of the steps because I get the Apache "It works" when pointing the browser to `http://localhost`.

I made the modifications in the files `/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` and `/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` as advised in the tutorials (basically telling Apache to use `libphp7.so` and not to deny access to the file system).

My `httpd-vhosts.conf` looks like this:

```
<Directory "/www">
  Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>

<Virtualhost *:80>
  VirtualDocumentRoot "/www/sites/%1/wwwroot"
  ServerName sites.test
  ServerAlias *.test
  UseCanonicalName Off
</Virtualhost>

<Virtualhost *:80>
  VirtualDocumentRoot "/www/sites/%-7+/wwwroot"
  ServerName xip
  ServerAlias *.xip.io
  UseCanonicalName Off
</Virtualhost>
```

I have a `www` directory at the top `/` level:

```
/www
├── home
└── sites
    ├── client1
    │   ├── assets
    │   └── wwwroot
    │       └── index.html
    ├── wordpress
```

When I type `client1.test` in the browser address bar, it displays the content of `index.html` correctly.

So the next step was to create a subdirectory `wordpress` within `sites` and download and unzip the latest wp version into this directory.

In the [2nd tutorial](https://www.davidgagne.net/2017/01/23/the-ultimate-guide-to-local-wordpress-development-on-a-mac/), it says "At this point you should be able to hit wordpress.test in your browser and start the WordPress installation process."

Well that doesn't work for me: I get "404 Not Found" message. My permissions look as follows:

```
drwxr-xrwx    5 root      wheel     160 Jun 19 12:39 client1
drwxrwxrwx   23 _www      wheel     736 Jun 19 15:34 wordpress
```

I noted that unlike the `client1` subdirectory, `wordpress` doesn't contain the `wwwroot` subdirectory. But I guess this isn't important here? I was expecting some installation steps to begin when entering `wordpress.test`.

Would anyone know possible reasons why I'm getting the 404 message? I'm on High Sierra 10.13.5.

Comment: Did you try moving the wordpress files into wordpress/wwwroot?  The way you have your config set up, it would need to have that structure.

Comment: @Devon yes I did that and instead of 404 I got `Error establishing database connection`. To clarify, in my `wpconfig.php` file I have a line `define('DB_NAME', 'wordpress');` and I had previously created this db in mysql (but not assigned a user to it explicitly). Despite this the establishing database connection error appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much digging, I found the answer.

@Devon was correct in that I should add the WordPress files (i.e., download them from the WP site, unzip them, and add them) to the subdirectory `wwwroot`.

The next error was `Error establishing database connection`, and apparently there is a problem with the version of mysql that I had been using. I had been using MySQL Community Server 8.0.11. But according to [this post](https://github.com/postlight/headless-wp-starter/issues/94#issuecomment-397891514) from an unrelated project, v8.0.11 of mysql has issues with php 7.1.

I completely uninstalled/deleted mysql v8.0.11 and then did `brew install mysql@5.7`.

After installing v5.7, I logged in to mysql (as root user), and just ran:

```
mysql> create database wordpress_db;
mysql> exit
```

I didn't create an extra user or specify privileges; that was it. When I now open `wordpress.test` in the browser, the installation script runs as expected.